# How do I mix 3D skeletal animations?

Tags: c++, opengl, skeletal-animation

I'm trying to create a 3D-model skeletal animation system for C++/Open GL. I would like to be able to **mix animations by allowing animations to only affect specific bones**.

My game has ride-able creatures, which affect the players legs to animate him sitting. But while he is sitting, the items he is holding must control his arms, independent of the legs.

I almost feel like hand-coding the bone rotations would be easiest, even if it means low animation quality.

How can I make this work?

Are particular model file formats better-suited for this?

Comment: Blending animations can easily be done by taking the transformation matrices from both animations and combining them. How to create an entire animation system is a pretty broad question, do you have something more specific you're stuck on?

Comment: You need to reinvent the wheel and understand how to implement an _animation blend tree_: http://www.chemical-games.com/?page_id=2201 http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3456/animation_blending_achieving_.php http://flohofwoe.blogspot.com/2009/01/animation.html